# Passport preference for United Arab Emirates and South Africa; US or Schengen

Tags: passports, uae, south-africa

We'll be travelling to both the UAE and South Africa shortly as dual citizens with both US and German citizens. A casual look seems to indicate that either passport will work.

Question:

Is one of these passports preferable for either country in terms of ease of entry or dealing with hotels, cars, flights, etc. ?

Comment: For UAE, either passport will work, though you get a longer validity for Germany (90 days) vs USA (30 days, extendable to 60). Otherwise, doesn't matter for UAE.

Answer (score 1):

**South Africa:** no difference; nationals of both USA and Germany are entitled to stay up to 90 days without a visa.

**UAE:** German nationals are allowed to stay up to 90 days within 180 days, while nationals of the USA can only stay up to 30 days.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Africa) [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates)

**Conclusion:** A German passport is better.